# Two left joins not working

Tags: mysql

EDIT: Ok, so I managed to get something but it only changes to table on the left side even though I gave 2 specific left joins.

```
SELECT speler.Roepnaam as team1, wedstrijd.Speler2ID as team2
FROM wedstrijd 
LEFT JOIN speler as player1 
ON wedstrijd.Speler1ID = speler.ID 
LEFT JOIN speler 
ON wedstrijd.Speler2ID = speler.ID WHERE speler.ID
```

Comment: Each table copy must have its own alias unique in its visibility scope.

Comment: I can't mark it as duplicate because this is from a different site, but that's largely because your question I believe is out of scope here on DBA anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590007/1066-not-unique-table-alias

Comment: I've tried giving it an alias and it worked, but somehow the right side of the table still hasn't changed from ID to the 'speler' name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT speler1.Roepnaam as team1,     -- unique alias for 1st value from 1st table copy
       speler2.Roepnaam as team2      -- unique alias for 2nd value from 2nd table copy
FROM wedstrijd 
LEFT JOIN speler as speler1           -- unique alias for 1st table copy
ON wedstrijd.Speler1ID = speler1.ID   -- join this 1st copy by its alias
LEFT JOIN speler as speler2           -- unique alias for 2nd table copy
ON wedstrijd.Speler2ID = speler2.ID   -- join this 2nd copy by its alias
```

Comment: It worked, you're a legend